# Is it possible to use KDevelop to debug ruby applications?

Tags: ruby, kdevelop

I has read that KDevelop has integrated Ruby support and was interested to test it. But unfortunately, it wasn't easy. First, i was not able to install KDevelop both in Ubuntu and Kubuntu - it's not in the packages, so apt-get install kdevelop does nothing. After enabling unsupported backports, i was able to install KDevelop and it even sucesfully started, but the only language available in 'create project from template' was C++. Is it works as intended (not installable in mainstream distributives, no projects for ruby etc) or i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe you should enable other sources (universe) for `apt`. I am able to install KDevelop in Kubuntu 10.04 using `apt-get`.

Comment: I have enabled unsupported backports and installed KDevelop via apt-get, but as i mentioned above it have only 'C++' project type. How to use it with Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of this posting, the Ruby support plugin for Kdevelop 4 is limited and not actively maintained. It is very unlikely that you will find packages for it, and it probably doesn't build against recent releases of KDevelop 4.